# Quiet hours vs silent hours

Tags: phrases, differences

I’ve seen some people use “silent hours” while others use “quiet hours” (in a studying lounge, Airbnb, etc). I searched dictionary for “silent” and “quiet”, and suppose that both phrases refer to “time to make as little noise as possible”. Would like to know the difference between the two phrases and which one is more commonly used. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

They are very similar, but it's a matter of adjusting expectations. "Quiet" could imply talking in soft voices so as not to disturb others, while "silent" suggests no talking at all, and similarly for other noise-making activities. In practice people will tend to do more than the term would suggest, so saying "silent" implies "quiet, but we really mean it" - so headphones if watching videos etc.